# Get value from object/array

Tags: javascript, arrays, object, find, response

I need to get the token only in a variable in JS.

```
    {
  "user": {
    "id": "string",
    "nickName": "string",
    "score": 0,
    "rank": 0
  },
  "token": "string"
}
```

This is my response saved in a variable but I only need to get the "String" value from the token

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you have stored this response in a variable E.g.:

```
let response = {
  "user": {
    "id": "string",
    "nickName": "string",
    "score": 0,
    "rank": 0
  },
  "token": "string"
}
```

You can extract the value from the "token" property like this

```
let tokenFromObject = response.token
```

or

```
let tokenFromObject = response["token"]
```

or

```
let { token } = response
```

Comment: When I do that I get an undefined

Comment: It would be helpfull to know the context this is in. What Code do you have and what do you want to do?

Comment: @Paulemeister , I've got a response and I put in in to text by doing return response.text after that I save the response in a variable and now I want the token only out of the variable

Answer (score 0):

You should be able to take the variable you got this json in and do this:

```
let a = {"user":{},"token": "string"}; // this is what you got

console.log(a["token"])  // a["token"] will give you "string"
```